# Как сделать так чтобы код выполнялся заново

Tags: php, mysqli, случайные-числа

Всем привет, я делаю проверку не совпадает ли число которое было сгенерированно с базой данных. И если оно совпало, как сделать так чтобы я вернул действие обратно(чтобы строчка выше опять выполнилась)?

[image: Безумие это повторение]

Еще раз. Хочу сделать так чтобы если оно не прошло проверку, то код заново выполнился. Или выполнился с сторчки выше опять.(с строчки где генерируется код)

Код

```
//Generate card number
$random = rand(1000,9999)
//Check
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `cardid` = '$random'");
$auth_url = url($client_id, $redirect_url, $scopes);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    exit()


}
```

Если можете то добавьте в код пожалуйста

Comment: помести всё в бесконечный цикл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while(true) {
  // Generate card number
  $random = rand(1000,9999)
  // Check
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `cardid` = '$random'");
  $auth_url = url($client_id, $redirect_url, $scopes);
  // Если число есть в таблице - выход из повторов
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) break;
}
```

Сам код не проверял - просто завернул его в бесконечный цикл с условием выхода.